# Excel UserForm Top Most Reset Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using this code to keep a userform as TOPMOST, I would like the TopMost to stop working when the main code has completed. I tried to set an if statement condition but can not get it to work. **I think the problem is the EXIT SUB. It should NOT be set to exit, BUT to RESET back when the IF condition is met.** I can not workout how to write the code to reset the userform back,

Q) Does anyone know how I can get the userform to reset back to a normal after the main code has finished running? my form is non module

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos _
  Lib "user32.dll" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
     ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
     ByVal X As Long, _
     ByVal Y As Long, _
     ByVal cx As Long, _
     ByVal cy As Long, _
     ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub KeepFormOnTop2()

    If Sheet20.Range("E24") = "Stopped" Then
        Exit Sub   ' if condition met then exit    
    Else
        Dim hWnd As Long
        Dim RetVal As Long

        Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
        Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
        Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
       
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
        RetVal = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
    End If
End Function
```

I am calling and trying to end it as such, I can call it but not end it, so it does not reset back

```
Private Sub ReportForm_Click

    Sheet20.Range("E24").Value = "Start" 'ADD START TO CELL
    Call KeepFormOnTop2 ' call TO START TOPMOST

''####################################################################

''+++++++++++++++++++++ RUN MAIN CODE HERE +++++++++++++++++++++++++

''####################################################################

    Sheet20.Range("E24").Value = "Stopped" 'ADD STOPPED TO SELL
    Call KeepFormOnTop2 ' call TO STOP TOPMOST
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like this and it works, I am calling and ending the TOMOST the same way as shown above

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos _
  Lib "user32.dll" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
     ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
     ByVal X As Long, _
     ByVal Y As Long, _
     ByVal cx As Long, _
     ByVal cy As Long, _
     ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub KeepFormOnTop2()

    If Sheet20.Range("E24") = "Stopped" Then
        Dim hWnd As Long
        Dim RetVal As Long

        Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
        Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2 ''THIS IS NEW FROM ABOVE CODE
        Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
        Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
        
        'DISABLE FORM TOPMOST  '''THIS IS NEW FROM ABOVE CODE
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
        RetVal = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)
        
    Else
        'MAKE FOR TOPMOST
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
        RetVal = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: tl;dr and didn't try, but the first two API function arguments should be of type `LongPtr` (instead of `Long`) in VBA7 declarations.